# How would you go about testing a USB cable for a short?

Tags: usb, cables, multimeter

I have had an issue with a USB cable blowing up a device when plugging it in (pop, burning smell) assuming a resistor blew. I'm trying to figure out if this was caused by the cable or the port.

If I use a multi meter to test the USB cable from a different power source, should I expect to see 5v been pwr and gnd, and nothing been d+ / d- and gnd?

I'm assuming a short from the power wire to either data wire could cause something like this to happen?

Comment: What kind is your "a device" that blows up? Is it a USB host, or a peripheral device? Where does the other end of your suspected cable go?

Comment: Depends on the supply. Some have the data pins tied together,  or with resistors as voltage dividers

Comment: Ah my apologies, it's a peripheral plugged into a usb port.

Answer (score 1):

If designed correctly the port itself should be able to handle shorts in any way possible. So disconnect the cable and make a regular resistance measurement between the wires. +5V, D+, D- and GND should all be isolated. If the cable is good I would go check the output voltage of the port.

Comment: A cable mis-manufactured with the supply voltage lines swapped could probably destroy a peripheral while only tripping a resettable overcurrent protector in the host.   Measuring voltage on a USB connector without shorting to the shell is a bit tricky, and unless one knows for a fact that the host has overcurrent protection, a bit risky.  It's also not entirely clear if the signal lines in a given device are going to be protected against bus voltage or worse, reversed bus voltage.

Comment: You're right. Will edit it tomorrow.

Comment: With regard to testing the cable, I'm thinking about testing a female ended cable and cutting it, accessing the cables and wiring them into boxes I can test with a multi meter. That way i can plug the cable into the test adapter and avoid shorting to the case, if that makes sense